# Upgrade from fedora 25 to 27 - Conflict issue

Tags: fedora, upgrade, error-handling, troubleshooting

I tried to upgrade from fedora 25 to fedora 27. When running

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=27 --allowerasing
```

I encountered a transaction check error regarding `python`. The error summary can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/bUYs69AY)

I paste here the first five lines

```
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py from install of python2-ipython-5.5.0-1.fc27.noarch conflicts with file from package python-ipython-console-3.2.1-8.fc25.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/__init__.py from install of python2-ipython-5.5.0-1.fc27.noarch conflicts with file from package python-ipython-console-3.2.1-8.fc25.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py from install of python2-ipython-5.5.0-1.fc27.noarch conflicts with file from package python-ipython-console-3.2.1-8.fc25.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.pyc from install of python2-ipython-5.5.0-1.fc27.noarch conflicts with file from package python-ipython-console-3.2.1-8.fc25.noarch
  file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/__init__.pyc from install of python2-ipython-5.5.0-1.fc27.noarch conflicts with file from package python-ipython-console-3.2.1-8.fc25.noarch
```

Any idea on how to overcome this issue and upgrade?

Comment: You could start by not skipping releases - upgrade to 26 first and then to 27.

Comment: Did you apply all the updates to F25 before attempting to upgrade to F27?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 : Thank you for your comment! Yes, first I run `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh`

Comment: What if you add `--best`?

Comment: @schaiba : Thanks for your comment. I tried to upgrde to f26, but I couldn't. Check this question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415059/cant-complete-upgrade-from-fedora-25-to-fedora-26

Answer (score 2):

Had exact same issue. Not as complex as it seems. You first need to do:
sudo dnf remove python-ipython-console

Then proceed with
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=27 --allowerasing
which will automatically reinstall ipython (which I presume was a faulty install).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure offhand what's causing this particular issue, but a general approach which works in most cases is: remove the package that's causing the problem, and add it back after the upgrade.

Of course, this doesn't work if it's a core package which can't be removed without breaking the system, and it's inconvenient if it's a package which a lot of things require, but neither of those should be the case with `python-ipython-console`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried first to upgrade to fedora 26, but I couldn't... See here.. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415059/cant-complete-upgrade-from-fedora-25-to-fedora-26

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, but I think I have tracked down the problem.  First, a question for you: are you using Sage? (package `sagemath`)  The Sage packages require `ipython-console`, but they seem to have something wrong with their dependencies.  It seems like the Sage packages aren't recognizing the new version of `ipython-console` in F27, so in the upgrade from F25, Sage is still expecting to see the older version of `ipython-console`.  The result is that the upgrade fails due to file conflicts.  The suggestion to remove `ipython-console`, then upgrade, seems right, but you need to be aware that you will also be uninstalling Sage and will need to reinstall it, too.  Backing up your Sage data before any of this would probably be a good idea.

Comment: That seems very plausible. Have you filed a bug against the sagemath package?