# Can't complete upgrade from fedora 25 to fedora 26

Tags: fedora, logs, upgrade, troubleshooting, dist-upgrade

I tried to upgrade from fedora 25 to fedora 26.
I followed the following commands, as explained in the journal

1. `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh`
2. `sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade`
3. `sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=26 --allowerasing`
4. `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot`

When running the last command, the system reboots and then grub pops-up. I boot the last kernel and then the Upgrade screen shows off.

That is the point when it stays there for a few seconds and then the system is rebooted in fedora 25.

Any idea on how to find out what is the issue?
I am not aware whether there are any log files.

The only thing I could do, was to take a [video of the procedure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpspjwden8vjhcy/VID_20180105_195259.3gp?dl=0)!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you get from `journalctl -b -1` (for logs from the previous boot) when the system comes back up? (Or `journalctl --since yesterday`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The first  54 lines can be found here https://pastebin.com/Gkdnj9QV Do you think more lines could be useful?

Comment: Maybe? There's definitely nothing useful there. :) Try `journalctl -p err` to just see errors...

Comment: In reverse order. You can see here https://pastebin.com/YJCpqGtv

Comment: I also tried `journalctl -r -p err | grep upgrade` and I get this https://pastebin.com/dfX5kEyE

Comment: Is it possibly [this issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1498207)? Do you have `updates-testing` enabled, or did you at some point? This might also explain your [other issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414988/upgrade-from-fedora-25-to-27-conflict-issue).

Comment: Hmmm... How can I tell it's python? Shall I remove `python` and then try to upgrade?

Comment: You probably can't remove python because too much will require it. But you can probably remove `python-ipython-console`, which I know is a problem from the other question because the output said so. :)

Comment: I just removed it. I will run again `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot` to see if it's fixed!

Comment: Still no luck. I get exactly the same. Here are the latest lines of 
`journalctl -r -p err` https://pastebin.com/zD5Xs6Hy . I also tried `journalctl -b -1 | grep upgrade` https://pastebin.com/znKtPPpm

Comment: Does going to 27 work now?

Comment: One more thing to check: how much disk space do you have free?

Comment: The space I have left in `/` is 5.1 gb, which I think is enough right? I could again `f27`, but I will have to download it, since I erased all rpm files related to `fc27` to free up some space. This means, that I will have to delete all the `*.fc26*.rpm` files as well.. Does it worth it? I also tried journalctl -b -1 | grep upgrade pastebin.com/znKtPPpm

Comment: Oh: dnf still logs outside of the journal. Can you check `/var/log/dnf.log`? Hopefully this will show the actual error.

Comment: It seems that there is a `python` issue... I am pasting only the last error summary https://pastebin.com/UbKbBapM The full file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0omydz6jwa7dzx/dnf.log?dl=0

Comment: Would it be ok to remove all the `PyQt4` packages? These are the ones https://pastebin.com/Ct63xGhk

Comment: I think probably. That might cause some KDE stuff to be removed, but you can put it back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71262/discussion-between-mattdm-and-thanos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your DNF log, the initial problem is disk space:

```
Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
   At least 2459MB more space needed on the / filesystem.
```

and then from today:

```
Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
   At least 359MB more space needed on the / filesystem.
```

which is closer. :) Then I *think* possibly there was a partial upgrade to 25 to 26 somewhere in there which blew up for reasons unknown, and now the issues remaining are dealing with duplicates from that.